# Swipe action left/right menu item on "jemise111 / react-native-swipe-list-view" react native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Hi I cant make to work swipe left/right action in react-native-swipe-list-view. I read the doc, but I didnt find any example.

You can see I successfully use some onpress actions in my code below. But **onLeftAction** doesnt work - it doesnt do anything (nor print to console)

My code:

```
<SwipeListView
        data={swipeListData}
    /*START ISSUE*/
        leftActionValue={70}
        onLeftAction={(data, rowMap) => {
            console.log("swipeleft");
        }
    /*END ISSUE*/
        }
        renderItem={(data, rowMap) => (
    /*HERE EVERYTHING WORKS*/
    
        )}
    
        renderHiddenItem={(data, rowMap) => (
    /*ALSO IN HERE*/ 
        )}
        leftOpenValue={75}
        rightOpenValue={-75}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onLeftAction` does not respond to `leftActionValue`.

You will need to define `leftActivationValue`, this will trigger `onLeftAction`.

Difference between the props:

> leftActionValue - TranslateX value for left action to which the row
> will be shifted after gesture release

> onLeftAction - fired when row shifted to - leftActivationValue

Reference: https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/blob/2f5cdec5ebd6ee320c42e4c9f477d1f072ecb40c/docs/actions.md